# Github desktop / Rstudio fail to authenticated and push

Tags: github, ssh, rstudio, ssh-keys

I am experiencing some issues with the authentification on github. 
(I work on a Mac). 
I wanted to create a new account and start all over again but things got quite complicate. I have then reset my SSH key and abandonned the project of a new account. I apparently successfully authenticated myself when creating the new SSH-key on my old account.

[image]

I have problems now when pushing from the **github desktop** and from **rstudio**. I have deleted and re-installed the desktop and sign up again but it still fails to authentification.

[image]

I experience the same issue with Rstudio even though the link to my new SSH-key seem to be correct.

[image]

When I `ls -al ~/.ssh` I get this

[image]

Do you see something irregular here ? How can I remove the old `githubt_rsa`? It may be this that causes the issues.

Any help is very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it happened to me before awhile ago.

You need to delete any old associated files from your old GitHub account and remove it from your current GitHub account. Then re add it back into your account.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you know exactly how I can delete all these files ?